# Removing a particular word from a file.

Tags: python-3.x

I am having issues with the below code on line 12, getting the error 'int' object is not subscriptable. I am just not sure how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
fname = input('Enter File:')
fhand = open(fname)
lst = list()
words = 0

for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith("Subject:Sakai"): continue
    words = line.split()
    revNumber = words[4]

if not words[6] =="in ":
    source = words[6].split("/")
    finalSrc = source[0]
    lst.append((revNumber,finalSrc))

else:
    source = words[7].split("/")
    finalSrc = source[0]
    lst.append((revNumber,finalSrc))

for revNumber,finalSrc in lst:
    print(revNumber,finalSrc)

print("There were",len(lst),"Subject lines in the file")enter code here
```

Comment: change `words = 0` to `words = []`

Comment: @WayneWerner, that is going to give an IndexError, `[][6]`.

Comment: ah, true. Maybe `None` would be a better initializer :P (though obviously won't fix their problem)

Comment: @WayneWerner, I don't think they really need it at all, I think they meant to be checking in the loop itself not outside.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously no line `.startswith("Subject:Sakai")` so you keep hitting *continue* and you never reach `words = line.split()`,  you have `words = 0` at the start of your code so `if not words[6] =="in "` causes your error because *words*  still points to an integer not a list.

```
In [1]: words = 0

In [2]: words[6]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fe50e40ed82c> in <module>()
----> 1 words[6]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I think your code is actually meant to be more like:

```
for line in fhand:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith("Subject:Sakai"):
        continue
    words = line.split()
    revNumber = words[4]

    if not words[6] =="in ":
        source = words[6].split("/")
        finalSrc = source[0]
        lst.append((revNumber,finalSrc))

    else:
        source = words[7].split("/")
        finalSrc = source[0]
        lst.append((revNumber,finalSrc))

for revNumber,finalSrc in lst:
    print(revNumber,finalSrc)
```

where you do the checking in the loop. You also don't need to declare variables in Python so you can remove the *words = 0* altogether. You still have the problem that no line `startswith("Subject:Sakai")` but without seeing the content that you will have to figure out yourself. It may be a case where you need to strip leading whitespace `if not line.lstrip().startswith("Subject:Sakai"):` or meant to use `in`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I removed words = 0 which fixed the not subscriptable error. After, I was able to fix my remaining issues! Thanks again!